# Constantly Update Values In VB (God Mode)

Tags: vb.net

I'm new(ish) to Visual Studio and would like to know how to constantly refresh a value in VB...

I'm currently making hacks ( A game trainer) for the game "Dishonored", I already have v1.0 released but all it does is (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaMEw.png) ...Really simple. I have since worked on the original and created this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLpAP.png) - But I can't get the God-Mode working :/ Here's my code:

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.CheckState = 1 Then
        WriteDMAInteger("Dishonored", GetModuleHandle("Dishonored", "Dishonored.exe") + &H100C810, {&H344}, 70, 1, 4)
    Else
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

But I'm not sure how to loop this value being updated... 
The buttons and everything else work fine... I just can't get the toggle's working :(
Please help
Thanks in advance, BLITZ

Comment: inb4, Ik but whilst I was trying to figure it out, I found that in the `Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged` Part of the code, when I backspaced `CheckBox1.CheckedChanged`I was greeted with these options: [Here](https://i.gyazo.com/a205cb0cf26578fe082645018a3c049a.gif) But after trying about 80% of them, gave up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Timer and set interval in millisecound for it.

```
Dim Timer1 As New Timer
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.CheckState = 1 Then
        AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
        Timer1.Interval = 500
        Timer1.Start()

    Else
        RemoveHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    WriteDMAInteger("Dishonored", GetModuleHandle("Dishonored", "Dishonored.exe") + &H100C810, {&H344}, 70, 1, 4)
End Sub
```

Comment: May have found something, but when I try to use it, the whole thing freezes and to cancel the loop I have to end the task in Task Manager `    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            Do
                WriteDMAInteger("Dishonored", GetModuleHandle("Dishonored", "Dishonored.exe") + &H100C810, {&H344}, 70, 1, 4)
            Loop Until CheckBox1.Checked = False
        End If
    End Sub`

Comment: This works great, but It freezes the whole application :( To cancel it I have to go in to Task Manager, I can give you the whole source code if you want?

Comment: sorry try to replace Dim Timer1 as Timer with   Dim Timer1 as New Timer